# get version number of sub components jboss, slf4j in mysql-connector-java-8.0.11 jar

Tags: java, mysql, jar, jboss

How to get version number of sub components that are `jboss`, `slf4j` and `c3p0` in java application.

I found `c3p0` version in `manifest.mf` file but could not find the other two component versions, which i want for licensing purpose.

Is there a way to get version number of these remaining two components i.e `jboss`, `slf4j`.

Answer (score 2):

1. In your JBoss lib Directory:
       Open the file jboss-system.jar
       Extract the file MANIFEST.MF from the META-INF directory.
       Open MANIFEST.MF with a text editor and then look at the property Specification-Version and Implementation-Version
2. If you are using eclipse then you can easily get it through java buildpath.